# Is there a way to install MySQL-python on python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have seen lots of similar questions on stackoverflow, but while all of them advice switching to other packages that support python 3.

The issue is following: the project that I have to run on python3 uses [`mysql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql) package, which appears to be a "virtual package" (whatever that means) and actually installs `MySQL-python` package, which is not an easy task - if at all possible.

So, is there a way to install MySQL-python on python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but if you're looking to interface with mysql in python 3, just use `mysqlclient`. Its a pure python interface to mysql, and I use it myself in production. Libraries like sqlalchemy also support it.